# How to create a hybrid app on Angularjs and Svelte

Tags: angularjs, svelte

I have a large Angularjs application. There is also a small project in Svelte.

I need to insert an svelte-application into the first project, how can this be done? How to transfer components? How to build a project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about including the compiled Svelte app inside of your AngularJS app I believe you can do this as follows:

1. Inside of your Svelte project, specify the DOM element within your `AngularJS` app that you wish to attach your Svelte app to:

```
 new App({
    target: document.getElementById('someElement'),
 });
```

1. Build your Svelte app (ie. `npm run build`).
2. Take the contents of your Svelte app's build folder and put them somewhere within your AngularJS project.
3. Inside of your AngularJS app's `index.html` (or wherever you want to load the Svelte app) load in your `bundle.js` via a `script` tag and you `bundle.css` via a `style` tag.

This should attach the app to the element (with ID `someElement`) specified above.